# Android DDMS mislabels the app

Tags: android, ddms

I'm running my app and watching the logs in DDMS. Sometimes the application name would change to "system_process". The app seems to be working properly. Anyone has see this? Does it have any implications?

Answer (score 0):

The system process is **not** your application and does not run any of your code.

However, some things which your code does will cause work to be done in the system process.

Comment: That means the label should go back to the app name after the system work is done, right? What I've seen is that once the label is changed to "system_proces", it never changes back.

Comment: No, the label for your application's process should not be anything else.  You are probably mistaking the system process for your application's process, perhaps because your application process no longer exists or has ceased to exist in the past and suddenly gets re-created in a new PID.

Comment: What I see in logcat is that the Tag column shows the tag I use for my app; the Text column shows the log text I intented; the PID did not change. Only the Application column changed my my application name to "system_process". My application is still working fine.

Comment: You are either misinterpreting the display, using a buggy device, a buggy ddms client, or a device & ddms client which are not compatible with each other.  Try running logcat from the adb shell of the device, to rule out compatibility problems.